# How to merge dataframes based on column names?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two tables (data frames). 1. One that contains years and production. 2. Another that contains years and area. I want to merge these two and get results as shown in table 3. How to do this is python3 (preferably using pandas)?

Table1

[image: Table 1]

Table2

[image: Table 2]

Result table:

[image: Result table]

Comment: What is `print (df2.info())` and `print (df2.info())` ?

Comment: kindly share your data as text, not pics

Answer (score 0):

IIUC use:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).T
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using this:

```
Dataframe df3    
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='Years')
```